# Problem with routing in react with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

hey guys I am learning react as I'm trying to build a website, I am facing problem with the routing using params and without. I have these routes in index.js,

This is book's home

```
<Route exact path="/books/bookshome" component={BookList} />
```

and another route to fetch individual books

```
<Route exact path="/books/:slug" component={SingleBook} />
```

The problem is whenever I open the `BookList`, an api request will be send by the `SingleBook` component and that returns an error. How can I avoid that?

I tried checking a condition in `useEffect` in `SingleBook` but it doesn't seem to work.

`if(slug !=="bookshome") { fetch }`

Is there a way to solve this issue or should I change the url ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the `Route`s in a `Switch`?

Comment: yes.....it is..

Comment: If they are in a `Switch` and the the `/books/bookshome` is on top, the other shouldn't ever be hit. Could you update your code to show a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices to use `/books` is for BookList component and `/books/:id or /books/:name` which should resolve your problem too.

If you want keep urls as is then try putting BookList route above the Single Book route with exact param only for BookList route

I suggest to change the URLs and follow best practices.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the BookList route above the SingleBook route and remove exact from slug route:

```
<Route exact path="/books/bookshome" component={BookList} />
<Route path="/books/:slug" component={SingleBook} />
```